# Is it necessary to always add ! to function and command

Tags: vimscript

I can't remember start from when and why, i always add `!` to `function` and `command`:

```
function! ..
...
endfunction

command! ...
```

But `:h E122` says:

```
            When a function by this name already exists and [!] is
            not used an error message is given.  There is one
            exception: When sourcing a script again, a function
            that was previously defined in that script will be
            silently replaced.
            When [!] is used, an existing function is silently
            replaced.  Unless it is currently being executed, that
            is an error.
            NOTE: Use ! wisely.  If used without care it can cause
            an existing function to be replaced unexpectedly,
            which is hard to debug.
```

In short, one should use `!` only when one need to replace an existing function defined in other scripts. But nothing good would happen if such replace happens, right? So it should be avoided?

I went through a few popular plugins on my machine, all of them use `!`, even for a script scope function, does that make sense? am i missing something?

Comment: I’ve been wondering the same thing myself lately, and omitting it in new code hasn’t given me trouble. I think it must be a change—IIRC, in older versions the bang was necessary to allow re-sourcing the file to work

Comment: It was changed in [`8.1.0515`](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.0515), and in [`8.1.0573`](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.0573). FWIW, I've removed the bangs everywhere in my vimrc/plugins and did not notice any issue. The only times where I still have to use a bang, are for functions defined at runtime inside other functions; typically for closures (see `:h func-closure`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When sourcing a script again, a function that was previously defined in that script will be silently replaced.

That's a fairly recent (Vim 8.1) change. Previously, you had to use `:function!` to redefine an existing function. As plugin writers very frequently reload their scripts during development (as its much faster than restarting Vim and restoring all context), you still see `:function!` in most plugins, although going forward, this isn't needed any longer.

Comment: Removing all of these `!` would, in some sense, break backwards compat, yes? I regularly have to work on systems where 7.4 is the only version available, and it's inconvenient to drop back a level to edit over scp when I'm already logged in to the system. (I have to use `v:val` instead of lambdas for exactly this reason.) Might be worth a comment.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: That would only bother contributors that just have an older Vim to work on, and they could resort to restarts or `:delfunction`. When using a plugin, it (normally) is only sourced once, so no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I also wondered at seeing this topic first time. I suspect that the whole story is due to VimScript version changes, however, personally I still see these points:

1. As it turns out, for a *script-local* function there's absolutely no difference between `function` and `function!`. Therefore, it becomes rather a matter of taste: some people may prefer "shorter" notation, but writing `function! s:myfunc()` clearly indicates that this thing is "silently re-sourceable" what I think isn't too bad.
2. For a global `function`, there's a small chance of a name clash catching, however many plugins tend to prefer autoloaded functions anyway, and a clash inside your own config is very unlikely.
3. Sometimes I also like `execute()`-ing things from a "scratch" buffer. Such stuff must be global and have a "bang" to allow subsequent overwrite.
4. Just a stupid habit of blindly writing `function!` and `command!` (yes, `command!` should be frowned upon too) ;-)

Comment: `4` is what i have been doing for a long time. `3` is a good point.

Answer (score 0):

This NOTE makes me spend some time searching for a wonderful solution

> ```
>         NOTE: Use ! wisely.  If used without care it can cause
>         an existing function to be replaced unexpectedly,
>         which is hard to debug.
> ```

I do not use `func!` in my init.vim. But after saving my init.vim twice, I get E122.

In many places, we can find advice like this:
from https://groups.google.com/g/vim_use/c/Rb1NQVl8fC8/m/ZhXqhDch_1QJ

> Put a ! after :function.

> To make sure a .vimrc is able to be sourced more than once, you need to do that;

> you also should make sure you have ! after each :command
> you define

> and wrap any autocommands in groups something like this:

```
augroup MyAutoCmds 
au! 
au ... 
au ...
augroup END
```

So I decide to do this:

> Just a stupid habit of blindly writing function! and command!